# If $f^{-1}[\{0\}]=g^{-1}[\{c\}]$ and $c$ is a regular value of $g$, is $0$ a regular value of $f$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was wondering. Suppose $f: \mathbb R^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ and $g:\mathbb R^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$ $(m, k<n)$ are two smooth functions such that $f^{-1}[\{0\}]=g^{-1}[\{c\}]$ and $c$ is a regular value of $g$. Is $0$ a regular value of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got us a counter example. Let $f\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2$ be the shifted projection $f(x,y,z) = (x-1,0)$. Then $${\rm D}f(x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$is never surjective. Also, let $g\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ be the same projection, in some sense: $g(x,y,z) = x$. Then $g^{-1}(1) = f^{-1}(0)$, $1$ is a regular value of $g$ because $\nabla g(x,y,z) = (1,0,0) \neq {\bf 0}$ always, but $0$ is not a regular value of $f$.